# PAPR used in PAM constellations

Tags: digital-communications

Can anybody explain me how to derive analytically the PAPR (Peak-to-Average Power Ratio ) for PAM constellations. E.g. 2-ASK (unipolar/bipolar), 8-ASK (unipolar/bipolar), 16-QAM, and 8-PSK?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please don't use "random" tags. I'm removing the unrelated tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You literally do what the name says:

Peak-to-Average Power Ratio

First you calculate the **average power**. Remember that power in the digital domain is just the square of the magnitude of the complex value!

That makes calculating the average power of a PSK extremely simple (every point has the same magnitude!). For constellations with multiple different amplitudes, you literally calculate the average, by summing all the magnitude squares of points, and then dividing by the number of points.

Then you calculate the **peak power**. That's just the square of the largest magnitude that any of the symbols in your constellation has.

Then you just divide, i.e, you calculate the **ratio** of the peak power to the average power.

That's it.